# (from $GOROOT) ($GOPATH not set) in IntelliJ idea

Tags: go, intellij-idea, environment-variables

I've started using the golang in IntelliJ Idea.

I have the following code

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "/github.com/zzz/stringutil"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf(stringutil.Reverse("!oG ,olleH"))
}
```

and also I have the following stringutil.go file

```
// Package stringutil contains utility functions for working with strings.
package stringutil

// Reverse returns its argument string reversed rune-wise left to right.
func Reverse(s string) string {
    r := []rune(s)
    for i, j := 0, len(r)-1; i < len(r)/2; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        r[i], r[j] = r[j], r[i]
    }
    return string(r)
}
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
src\github.com\zzz\hello\hello.go:5:2: cannot find package "src/github.com/zzz/stringutil" in any of:
    C:\Go\src\src\github.com\zzz\stringutil (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set)
```

How can I configure the env variables through Intellij so I can run the program?

Answer (score 8):

This is the quick fix for this issue. I am using inttelliJ idea as my editor. I am using MAC

1. Go to preferences
2. Search for GO under language & frameworks
3. If your look for **GOROOT** it should be like screen shot below

   [image]
4. If you look for GOPATH the setting should be like screen shoot below

[image]

5. And this is my full path of the project. You can customize it to
   follow your needs. My project name is **adit** */Users/mmdc/Documents/mataharimall-development/www/go/src/github.com/mataharimall/adit*

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to remove slash at start of "`/github.com/zzz/stringutil`". It should be "`github.com/zzz/stringutil`".

Then, you need to define environment variable **GOPATH** and set it to some writeable directory.

You can see this guide for setting up GOPATH on windows: http://www.wadewegner.com/2014/12/easy-go-programming-setup-for-windows/

From above:

1. create a `C:\Projects\Go` folder as my root Go workspace
2. Create the GOPATH environment variable and reference your Go
       workspace path. To add, click `System-> Advanced system settings-> Environment Variables`... and click New... under System variables
3. Set the variable name to `GOPATH` and value to your `Go workspace path`
       (e.g. `C:\Projects\Go`)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, remove the slash of "/github.com/zzz/stringutil", like this "github.com/zzz/stringutil",
you can use idea or vscode, it can auto add to imports, new golanger. ^_^'

Answer (score -1):

If you installed via homebrew, just do:

```
brew info go
```

And it gives indications for your $GOROOT. Mine is:

```
You may wish to add the GOROOT-based install location to your PATH:  
    export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin
```

Also, don't forget to source your bash profile! It should work now. If not, try to do `File/ Invalidate Caches/ Restart...` in IntelliJ Idea.